# Can we connect a webhook with Google PubSub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to stream data from external webhook/ RSS feed into my Dataflow. I was thinking of using pub/sub to receive the messages and then process it in Dataflow. However, I couldn't find an option do to so.

Is there a better way of doing this in GCP as a managed service other that me setting a receiver queue server which listens to input stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choice of PubSub is the right one! For publishing the messages, you have 2 solutions:

- Either your webhook can initiate a OAuth authentication with a service account and, so, you can add the access_token in the header of your request to PubSub for publishing directly the message
- Or (because I never see a webhook able to generate an access token!), you have to set up a webserver for accepting your webhook request. This webserver simply catch the HTTP call and publish the message to PubSub. You can use Cloud Function, Cloud Run or App Engine.

If you have a lot of concurrent message, I recommend you to use Cloud Run, it will be cheaper. I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e)